Apache Kafka Kraft - Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request
acks = -1
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092, localhost:9094, localhost:9096]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-4
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    enable.metrics.push = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
    partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
    partitioner.class = null
    partitioner.ignore.keys = false
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 3
    retry.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

2024-10-18T20:00:49.577+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.k.c.t.i.KafkaMetricsCollector        : initializing Kafka metrics collector
2024-10-18T20:00:49.577+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2024-10-18T20:00:49.580+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.7.0
2024-10-18T20:00:49.580+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 2ae524ed625438c5
2024-10-18T20:00:49.580+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1729270849580
2024-10-18T20:00:49.583+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Node -2 disconnected.
2024-10-18T20:00:49.583+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-10-18T20:00:49.583+03:00  WARN 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Bootstrap broker localhost:9094 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2024-10-18T20:00:49.587+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Node -3 disconnected.
2024-10-18T20:00:49.587+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 3 due to node -3 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-10-18T20:00:49.587+03:00  WARN 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Bootstrap broker localhost:9096 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2024-10-18T20:00:49.587+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] ProducerId set to 1003 with epoch 0
2024-10-18T20:00:49.701+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Cluster ID: nQCoigKGSP22Wno_34Ez0Q
2024-10-18T20:00:49.709+03:00  INFO 5480 --- [card-composer-service] [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.



I get this error when I'm  trying to execute request :
{
    "listOfWords": "side;main;plot;joke;joker;circus;",
    "onlyTranslate": false
}

My ProducerConfig:
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Properties;

@Component
public class KafkaProducerRequest {
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092,localhost:9094,localhost:9096");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("image-handler-topic", message);

        producer.send(producerRecord);
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    }
}

DockerFile:
version: "3.9"
networks:
  main-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  volume-kafka-1:
  volume-kafka-2:
  volume-kafka-3:

services:
  kafka1:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - main-network
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka1:9093,1@kafka2:9095,2@kafka3:9097
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=nQCoigKGSP22Wno_34Ez0Q
    volumes:
      - volume-kafka-1:/bitnami/kafka
  kafka2:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - "9094:9092"
    networks:
      - main-network
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9094,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9095
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka1:9093,1@kafka2:9095,2@kafka3:9097
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=nQCoigKGSP22Wno_34Ez0Q
    volumes:
      - volume-kafka-2:/bitnami/kafka
  kafka3:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - "9096:9092"
    networks:
      - main-network
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=2
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9096,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9097
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka3:9096
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka1:9093,1@kafka2:9095,2@kafka3:9097
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=nQCoigKGSP22Wno_34Ez0Q
    volumes:
      - volume-kafka-3:/bitnami/kafka
  ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:v0.7.1
    ports:
      - "9898:8080"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka1:9092,kafka2:9094,kafka3:9096
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=kraft
    networks:
      - main-network

I think it's something wrong with my Kafka Configuration but I can't realize the problem because I'm new to Apache Kafka Kraft D: so I wish you could help me.
My consumer also shows this log (I have added a third node) :
2024-10-18T20:04:41.029+03:00  INFO 16880 --- [image-handler-service] [           main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-instance-1-1, groupId=instance-1] Discovered group coordinator kafka3:9096 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
2024-10-18T20:04:41.029+03:00  INFO 16880 --- [image-handler-service] [           main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-instance-1-1, groupId=instance-1] Group coordinator kafka3:9096 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable. isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.
2024-10-18T20:04:41.029+03:00  INFO 16880 --- [image-handler-service] [           main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-instance-1-1, groupId=instance-1] Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator kafka3:9096 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)


Using an even number of controller nodes is not recommended in any leader election setup. By the way, Kafka has an official Docker image; why use a different one?

Thank you for advice I'll try it later. Idk, this one popular so why not

Can you clarify "fixed it but get another headache" ?

I fixed the problem I had before :
Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition image-handler-topic-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now

but got this error I have now.

I've added a new broker but unfortunately it didn't help although I've add some new details to the post. Anyway thank for your advice it is useful.

Is there something you hope to gain from multiple controllers all on one computer, sharing the same disk, RAM and network?

It's just a training project, so I use Docker to host my nodes.

I understand that. That doesn't explain why you need more than one of any component, so even separate them. Get one broker fully working with a client. Scale it later... Minikube and Strimzi make this much easier than using Docker Compose. (Aside - You're not actually using Spring Boot in the code, other than the Component scanner. Use Spring-kafka or Spring Cloud Streams if you really want Spring integration). Otherwise, your "request" method should accept both the message and a preconfigured, non-closed Producer. You can re-use a producer across the lifecycle of the whole application

minikube + strimzi were really helpful althought a little harder to configure. I fixed this issue a longer time ago but have answered only now :D
